# Creating Follow Up intent in API.AI

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a Chatbot through API.AI. Now my chatbot has a flow and it responds based on the users query. So I have created many Follow up Intents. But my follow up intents are not connecting. It is returning the same respinse for the initial question. Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Would help to see what your intent looks like. From what you're saying though, it may be that the previous question is not getting the answer its looking for so it will just continue asking it until it does. Check your entity value under action within your intent.